# MonoDroid: Unable to Debug to an Android 4.0.3 Device

Tags: android, debugging, monodevelop, xamarin.android, tablet

We're able to debug to other devices, but our new Android 4.0.3 ASUS Transformer Prime tablet errors out when trying to debug Mono for Android code via MonoDevelop on a Mac. Eclipse works. If we deploy the APK manually to the device it works.

If we compile the app to an APK and manually deploy it to the device, it works fine.

When we run an app in debug from MonoDevelop we get this log dump:

```
05-29 11:37:29.460: I/ActivityManager(194): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.newyork.locker/police.locker.SplashScreen bnds=[592,202][688,298]} from pid 534
05-29 11:37:29.570: D/dalvikvm(3958): Late-enabling CheckJNI
05-29 11:37:29.590: I/ActivityManager(194): Start proc com.newyork.locker for activity com.newyork.locker/police.locker.SplashScreen: pid=3958 uid=10089 gids={3003, 1015, 1006}
05-29 11:37:29.640: I/dalvikvm(3958): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 10...
05-29 11:37:29.640: D/WindowManager(194): adjustConfigurationLw, config:{1.0 0mcc0mnc (no locale) layoutdir=0 sw800dp w800dp h1232dp xlrg port ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/v} mLidOpen:-1 mHasDockFeature:true mHasHallSensorFeature:true config.hardKeyboardHidden:2
05-29 11:37:29.650: D/OpenGLRenderer(534): Flushing caches (mode 1)
05-29 11:37:29.680: D/OpenGLRenderer(534): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-29 11:37:29.720: I/ActivityThread(3958): Pub com.newyork.locker.__mono_init__: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
05-29 11:37:29.720: D/dalvikvm(3958): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.newyork.locker/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x410c6120
05-29 11:37:29.720: D/dalvikvm(3958): Added shared lib /data/data/com.newyork.locker/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x410c6120
05-29 11:37:29.740: E/mono(3958): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
05-29 11:37:29.740: E/mono(3958): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
05-29 11:37:29.800: I/monodroid-gc(3958): environment supports jni NewWeakGlobalRef
05-29 11:37:29.800: I/mono(3958): Stacktrace:
05-29 11:37:30.540: I/ActivityManager(194): Process com.newyork.locker (pid 3958) has died.
05-29 11:37:30.540: W/ActivityManager(194): Force removing ActivityRecord{416425a0 com.newyork.locker/police.locker.SplashScreen}: app died, no saved state
05-29 11:37:30.550: D/Zygote(108): Process 3958 terminated by signal (11)
05-29 11:37:30.560: D/WindowManager(194): adjustConfigurationLw, config:{1.0 0mcc0mnc (no locale) layoutdir=0 sw800dp w800dp h1232dp xlrg port ?uimode ?night finger -keyb/v/h -nav/v} mLidOpen:-1 mHasDockFeature:true mHasHallSensorFeature:true config.hardKeyboardHidden:2
05-29 11:37:30.580: W/InputManagerService(194): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4159d858
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turing off Fast Deployment fixed it.

[image]